# what will be sql query for this

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

i want to Find out `role.id` by searching `role.name` and then retrieve all users  by matching their `user_id = founded role.id`

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: what you trying to do

Comment: select * from user join Role on Role.id=user.role where role.name='provider';

Comment: When composing a good Stack Overflow question do try and post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and not screenshots that often contain nothing but irrelevant cutter like action links we can't click.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will work:

```
select id,user_id,username from (select id from Role where name = 'provider') as t
join
user u on t.id = u.role
```

Comment: you have used sub-query but i was trying using join only i got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN role on user.role  = role.id WHERE role.name = 'provider'
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.